# how to define class based views in url.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I created a class based view for Login and Logout which works completely fine when called with .as_view() but if i use same for another app it gives me function object has no attribute as_view

created a class based view
added it to url.py
created new app->model->form->class based view

secondApp/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage, BadHeaderError
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.views.generic import CreateView, View
from django.conf import settings

from .forms import *
from .models import *
from login.models import User
class addDirector(CreateView):
    form_class = addDirectorMultiForm
    template_name = 'admin/add_director_account.html'
    success_url = 'administrator/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form['user'].save()
        profile = form['profile'].save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

urls.py

```
from administrator import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #accounts
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('accounts/login', LoginView.as_view(), name = 'LoginView'),

    # Admin 
    path('administrator/', views.admin_home_view, name = 'admin_home_view'),
path('administrator/add_director', views.addDirector.as_view(), name = 'addDirector'),
]
```

error_message:

path('administrator/add_director', views.addDirector.as_view(), name = 'addDirector'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: Did you by any chance defined a function with the name `addDirector` in that view as well?

Comment: No. But there is Home_view which is defined as a function

Comment: Update: I changes Home view to a class based view now that also gives the same error

Comment: Pardon me if I'm missing something, but your code shows that you have NOT imported the class from the views. You have to do: `from some_app.views import addDirector` and then do `addDirector.as_view()` for it to work.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that line in the code given here  but I'm importing it as from administrator import views.